# Transforming plane to fit user-defined points

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a plane to fit four user-specified points. I tried creating the vertices and faces of a geometry manually, but while the geometry is created just fine, the mapped texture is warped at the boundary of the geometry’s faces.

What's the proper way to transform a plane given four coordinates?

Comment: do you want to achieve something like this? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/gmtLf02u)